# How to check if an element has class d-none inside ejs template?

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, ejs

I am running a node project, I would like to include a script based on the condition that another element is displayed or not (bootrstrap d-none)

I tried something like this :

```
<% if ($("#headerMenu").hasClass("d-none")) %>
```

Comment: You can create an external js file and write your logic there. 
do something like this
 ` $("#headerMenu").hasClass("d-none") ? console.log(true) : console.log(false) ; `
 replace `console.log()` with your logic

Answer (score 0):

You can set up the template to load a JavaScript file, when you can put all client-side JavaScript code related to the template. It is in this js file where you put your check, thus:

```
$(function() {
    if( $('#headerMenu').hasClass('d-none') ) {
        //your code
    }

    //OR
    if( $('#headerMenu').is('.d-none') ) {
        //your code
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I created the js file, inside your if statement I want to include an external file before </body>, do you know how to achieve that?

PS: my external file contains a <script></script> code

Comment: JavaScript files don't contain `script` tags, which is a HTML tag, providing a way to add js files to a web application. What do you want to achieve? Maybe someone can show you how to do that.